# mod_rewrite rule for move specific GET parameter to url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please someone tell me how to write a rule for the following situation:

I have url like this:

```
/about/?ContentId=144&year=2012&id=44
```

And i need to move ContentId value to url string, but leave another get parameters. Like this:

```
/about/144/?year=2012&id=44
```

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try, plis

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}      ^ContentId=(\d+)\&(.*)    
RewriteRule ^about/  /about/%1/?%2 [R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks! All works find. No works, if I have only one parameter (ContentId), but adding * after & in first line fix this.